# Unable to create directory on server - digital ocean droplet & serverpilot

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, server, digital-ocean

I want to back up my WordPress site which is installed on a Digital Ocean droplet. Tried various backup plugins but none of them worked.

I am getting the below response when I try to install any plugin. Also, when I try to upload a file through the media tab of WordPress, the progress bar shows 100% but ends up with an HTTP error.

```
Warning: mkdir(): No space left on device in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/jam-jam/public/wp-content/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/lib/functions.php
```

Then, in terminal executed the following

```
root@ubuntu-1gb-blr1-01:/# ls
backups  etc             lib         mnt   run   swapfile  var
bin      home            lib64       opt   sbin  sys       vmlinuz
boot     initrd.img      lost+found  proc  snap  tmp       vmlinuz.old
dev      initrd.img.old  media       root  srv   usr


 root@ubuntu-1gb-blr1-01:/# df -h
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev            490M     0  490M   0% /dev
    tmpfs           100M   11M   89M  11% /run
    /dev/vda1        30G   30G     0 100% /
    tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/0
```

Then I tried executing the following the command

sudo chmod 777 -R /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/jam-jam/

**Response from server:**

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/jam-jam/': No space left on device
```

Also executed the following but same response :

```
 sudo chown -R serverpilot:serverpilot /srv/users/serverpilot/apps
```

*Configuration:
ubuntu-1gb-blr1-01 1 GB / 30 GB Disk / BLR1 - Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64
Only 1 app (Wordpress) installed through server pilot*

Just a beginner in Linux. Looking for an answer.

Comment: Looks like your droplet is full - one likely culprit is your `wp-content/uploads/` directory, though I guess you'd notice if you had added 30GB worth of content. What is the result of running `du -h /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/jam-jam/public/wp-content`? You should also list out contents in this directory recursively and look for directories created by the backup plugins you've tried.

Comment: Run `find . -type d /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/jam-jam/public/wp-content` to list directories recursively in `wp-content` - look for directories created by backup plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Your droplets root partition is full - no way around this other than adding more space through DigitalOcean or deleting some files

```
/dev/vda1        30G   30G     0 100% /
```